# Front-end and back-end mixing or leave it separate

Tags: java

Which is the best practice on the below?

1. Front-end code running in different server (Nginx or Apache httd server) and Back-end code running in different server (Tomcat Server)
2. Front-end code and Back-end code running in same port (Tomcat Server). Front-end code moved to static folder in Spring Boot

Thanks

There are 2 approaches - same server or different server. Both will work

Expected: Which one is the best practice and why?

Comment: Both will work, both approaches have pros and cons, choose the one for you. If you don't know or care, go simpler.

Comment: There are no "best practices," just good practices in context.

Comment: @PetrJaneček which one you would choose and why?

Answer (score 1):

Always depends on business rules:

1. running in different servers comes with distribuide arquitecture that comes with better individual maintain, resilience and portability, but it requires more time to develop and mount and maintaining multiples services up.
2. running on the same server have better communication beteween services, better integral mantaining. But, it has much less resilience due to has only one service with all the system, if it go off, the waste es worst.

Nevertheless, it up to business rules.